# How to initiate an index for an object being created in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an app where one can create an object called an item. I want to access this object's index in the array of items for another method I am writing. However, when I console.log the item's index, I always get undefined.

I am assigning each item a unique id using nanoid, and I am wondering if there is some kind of similar tool for assigning each object an index? This is my `addItem` function which handles instantiating a new item:

```
 function addItem(name) {
    const newItem = { id: "item-" + nanoid(), name: name, //index: ? };
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  }
```

This is defined in my App component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import './App.css';

function App(props) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.items);

  function deleteItem(id) {
    const remainingItems = items.filter(item => id !== item.id);
    setItems(remainingItems);
  }

  function moveLeft(index) {
    console.log(index)
  }

  const itemList = items
  .map(item => (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      index={item.index}
      name={item.name}
      key={item.id}
      deleteItem={deleteItem}
      moveLeft={moveLeft}
    />
  ));


  function addItem(name) {
    const newItem = { id: "item-" + nanoid(), name: name, //index: ? };
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  }


  return (
    <div className="form">
      <Form addItem={addItem} />
      <ul className="names">
        {itemList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and passed down to my item componenet:

```
import React from "react";
import {  Button, Card, CardContent, CardHeader } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default function Item(props) {
    return (
        
      <Card>
        <CardContent>
         <CardHeader> {props.name}</CardHeader>
          <Button onClick={() => props.deleteItem(props.id)}>
            Delete <span className="visually-hidden"> {props.name}</span>
          </Button>
          </CardContent>
          <CardContent style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
             <i className="arrow left icon" onClick={() => props.moveLeft(props.index)} style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
            <i className="arrow right icon"  style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
           </CardContent>
        </Card>
        
    );
  }
```

I am attempting to access the index so that I can eventually write a method to move the element of the array to the left or right, which is why that moveLeft method is coded in.

Any advice would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Why not just `index: items.length` before updating the list to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `itemList` using `map()` you get access not only to every element in the list but also their corresponding index in that list. Check [map() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax).

With that in mind, `itemList` creation would be something like this:

```
const itemList = items
  .map((item, index) => (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      index={index}
      name={item.name}
      key={item.id}
      deleteItem={() => deleteItem(index)}
      moveLeft={() => moveLeft(index)}
    />
  ));
```